# Read formdata from redirected page in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, form-data

We are trying to integrate third payment gateway with Angular 5.

After transaction completion, payment gateway will route to our custom response page with details of transaction through form data.

Challenge we are facing is - we are unable to read the request formdata in our angular component to display the transaction status to end user.

Could someone share the sample snippet to read input request formdata in angular if you have already done in your work.

We are beginners and still doing research for development.

Thanks SP.

Attaching the project,where we are stuck at check out 3

Location of component ...

```
angular2-cybersource-silent-order-post/src/app/components/
```

[Angular Project](https://github.com/sonukapoor/angular2-cybersource-silent-order-post.git)

Comment: It would probably be useful if you posted some of your code or html.  Even if it's very simple or basic.

Comment: Austin - Updated the question with project link and the location of the component where we need to read the form data coming.